# How to keep a table removed from code

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have a database project and want to keep a table as a backup on the production database but it shouldn't be part of the code anymore.

Even if I rename the table before generating the deployment script the rename is detected (via a search for named constraints I guess) and the renamed table will be dropped.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Use the option: "Do not drop objects in target"?  That's what I always turned on for pushes to Prod just because I wasn't comfortable dropping something that might have been created out of process.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround, but if the goal is to prevent this table from being created on new deployments (where it doesn't already exist), but keep it on deployments where it's already been added, then you could keep it in the code and add a [post-deploy script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj889461(v=vs.103).aspx) to delete it if it doesn't contain any data.

Or you could write your own "plugin" for the database deployment [Customize Database Build and Deployment by Using Build and Deployment Contributors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268597.aspx)